# How to refresh an instance variable list in a method within the same class in Python?

Tags: python, oop, instance, instance-variables

I have a class that has a list inside the `__init__` method that grabs a list of items from an API and stores it to the instance variable. Below I have named this list `self.mylist`

```
class Test:

    def __init__(self):
        self.mylist = []

        getlist = api.getValue('system/list')

        if isinstance(getlist, Error.restError):
            logger.error("ERROR: %s", _ret)
            self.mylist = []
        else:
            self.mylist = getlist[0]

    def getListObj(self, cname):

        for obj in self.mylist:
            if obj.get('CNAME', '') == cname:
                return obj
```

The issue I have now is that the list remains the same even if any of the parameters change in one of the object in that list. I want to refresh the list every time the `getListObj` method is called. I tried this below but it did not work. Basically trying to reset `self.mylist` by calling the API again and making sure I have the latest values in the list.

```
class Test:

    def __init__(self):
        self.mylist = []

        getlist = api.getValue('system/list')

        if isinstance(getlist, Error.restError):
            logger.error("ERROR: %s", _ret)
            self.mylist = []
        else:
            self.mylist = getlist[0]

    def getListObj(self, cname):
        getlist = api.getValue('system/list')

        if isinstance(getlist, Error.restError):
            logger.error("ERROR: %s", _ret)
            self.mylist = []
        else:
            self.mylist = getlist[0]

        for obj in self.mylist:
            if obj.get('CNAME', '') == cname:
                return obj
```

Comment: That code looks like it should work. How are you determining that it's not working?

Comment: How fresh does your data really need to be? What if it goes stale while you're working with it, *after* calling `getListObj`? And if you're going to retrieve fresh data from the API every time you call `getListObj`, why store `self.mylist` at all?

Comment: I recommend moving the duplicate code into a single method.